# How to sort order of menus?

Tags: navigation

I am using the sitemap module and have enabled 3 menus to display. However, I dont like the order the menus are being displayed in. Is there a way to change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this patch http://drupal.org/node/1529708#comment-6633022
If you need something more specific you can use hook_site_map() to add things to your sitemap and take a look at the _site_map_menus() function.

Comment: Thank you @DnBase
How would I go about applying the patch? Just paste it in my site_map folder and run update.php?

Comment: @kine456 The lines with + are added and - are deletedFor small patches you can

Comment: @kine456 This patch only applies on 7.x-1.x-dev so take that one. Then if you use netbeans just right click on the site_map module folder go to Tools > Apply diff patch. For Eclipse go to Team > Apply Patch.

Comment: Thank you @DnBase.
I am using Netbeans but am getting this error message: The patch cannot be applied in the selected context.